# saving the child fields on a failed validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic, nested-attributes

I am using formtastic like this

```
class Court < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tournament    
end

class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :courts, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :courts, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
  validates :name, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 100 }
end
```

and all works fine but on a failed validation of the tournament form the courts that were created are not preserving on a failed form.

here is my controller

```
def new
  @tournament = Tournament.new
  1.times do
    @tournament.courts.build
  end

def create
  @tournament = Tournament.new(params[:tournament])
```

i assumed that i could do something like this in the create but no go

```
    if params[:tournament][:courts_attributes]
         params[:tournament][:courts_attributes].each { |attribute| 
             @tournament.courts.build(attribute)
        }
      end


<%= semantic_form_for @tournament do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :number_courts, :hint => "How many courts are available?" %>

        <%= f.semantic_fields_for :courts do |builder| %>
            <%= render :partial => "court_fields", :locals => { :f => builder } %>
            <span class="links">
             <%= link_to_add_fields "Add More Court", f, :courts %>
            </span>
        <% end %>
```

partial

```
<div class="nested_fields">
<%= f.input :name %>
<%= f.input :address %>
<%= f.input :city %>
<%= f.input :state %>
<%= f.input :zip %>
<%= f.input :phone %>
<%= f.input :contact_name %>
<%= link_to_remove_fields "Remove Court", f %>
</div>
```

UPDATE---

here is my create action

```
def create
  @tournament = Tournament.new(params[:tournament])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @tournament.save
      format.html { redirect_to @tournament, notice: 'Tournament was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @tournament, status: :created, location: @tournament }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
        end
```

also here there the params just in case that will help

```
Processing by TournamentsController#create as HTML
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xv+p7QdpkJdEUaTGqrKue63869hlwh3Zv1xvkO5qx6A=", "tournament"=>{"name"=>"", "sport_id"=>"1", "entry_fee"=>"", "start_date"=>"", "end_date"=>"", "number_courts"=>"", "courts_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"hello", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1318725283928"=>{"name"=>"asdfsadfas", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1318725286739"=>{"name"=>"asdfasdfa", "_destroy"=>"false"}}, "available_times"=>"", "available_end_times"=>"", "min_games"=>"", "time_allowed"=>"1:15", "number_teams_per_bracket"=>"1", "gender_id"=>"1", "entry_deadline"=>"", "age_limit"=>"", "rules"=>"", "coach_meeting"=>"0", "meeting_location"=>"", "meeting_date"=>"", "future_tournament"=>"0", "private_service"=>"0", "add_blog"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Create Tournament"}
```

any ideas on how to preserve the data over a failed validation

Comment: Can you please post your form? Also, `1.times` ??

Comment: @bricker - sorry for the 1.times ....i changed it from 25 times and forgot to remove the loop..posting the form now

Comment: Yeah I figured that was the case, it just seemed silly when I first looked at it.

Comment: Can you also post all of your controller's `create` method

Comment: @maxenglander - sure...one sec...doing it now

Comment: @maxenglander - posted and also added my params just in case that may help

Comment: also the courts are not saving...strange ...not sure why

Comment: Your Courts will not save if the Tournament fails to save - this is how Rails works out of the box. In your case, I think it would be a bad idea for the Courts to save even though their Tournament does not save. This creates a maintenance headache of having to retroactively attach the courts to the Tournament once it succeeds in saving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that when you try to create a Tournament, and the validation fails, its child Courts are not actually created. What you want is for the Court data that was entered on the Tournament form to be preserved across creation attempts. Does that sound correct?

I haven't used formatastic. However, if its API is really just comprised of wrappers around Rails form helpers, then I would give this a shot:

```
    <%= f.semantic_fields_for :courts do |builder| %>
        <%= render :partial => "court_fields", :collection => @tournament.courts, :locals => { :f => builder } %>
        <span class="links">
         <%= link_to_add_fields "Add More Court", f, :courts %>
        </span>
    <% end %>
```

Notice the change to the rendering of the court fields partial.

When you attempt to create a tournament, this should render the court you built in `TournamentsController.new`. When the attempt fails, it should render the courts that were input during the first attempt.

Comment: for some reason the courts are not saving at all

Comment: Do you mean the Courts are not saving even though their Tournament DOES save; or even though their Tournament DOES NOT save. If the former, that's a problem. If the latter, that's expected behavior.

Comment: i mean the tournament is saving but the courts are not, i even added this to the model   attr_accessible :courts_attributes

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of `:reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }`. As far as I can tell, your Court form fields do not have an input for `:content`. Therefore, `a[:content].blank?` will always evaluate to true, and your Courts won't be saved. Perhaps you want to use something like `:reject_if => :all_blank`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4301/discussion-between-tamer-and-maxenglander)